# PHP / SQL - Get sum of another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have two tables in my MySQL database. One is called **players** and the other table is called **worlds**. Each player has a "level" and a "world" column. What I want to achieve is to fill up the columns in the table **world** based on the column values from table **players**. I want to first of all get the sum of players on that world and also an average of their levels.

My tables look like this:

Table: Players

```
+-------+-------+--------+----------+-------+--------------+---------+--------+
|  id   | name  |  sex   | vocation | level | achievements |  world  | online |
+-------+-------+--------+----------+-------+--------------+---------+--------+
| 24471 | John  | Male   | None     |    92 |            3 | Antica  |      1 |
| 24493 | Bob   | Male   | None     |    76 |           19 | Amera   |      0 |
| 24535 | Sam   | Male   | None     |    75 |            0 | Antica  |      0 |
| 24574 | Sarah | Female | None     |    78 |           23 | Beneva  |      1 |
| 24673 | Carl  | Male   | None     |    75 |           10 | Belobra |      1 |
+-------+-------+--------+----------+-------+--------------+---------+--------+
```

Table: Worlds

```
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+---------------+--------------+
| id |  name   | players | online | avglvl | totalexp |   location    |     pvp      |
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | Amera   |       0 |      0 |      0 |        0 | North America | Open PvP     |
|  2 | Antica  |       0 |      0 |      0 |        0 | Europe        | Open PvP     |
|  3 | Astera  |       0 |      0 |      0 |        0 | North America | Optional PvP |
|  4 | Belobra |       0 |      0 |      0 |        0 | South America | Optional PvP |
|  5 | Beneva  |       0 |      0 |      0 |        0 | Europe        | Optional PvP |
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

So for example, we can see that the players **John** and **Sam** have the world **Antica**. Therefore, Antica should have the value "2" under the player column in the table world. But only John is online on Antica. So the world Antica should have the value "1" under the column "online" in the table "world". And so on. I also want their average level on that world.

How can I achieve this with PHP by making an SQL query?

First I need to get all the world names (I think?) and loop through them. And then get the following details for each world:

- Player amount
- Online amount
- Average level amount

And then make an update in to worlds table with those values..

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you post something that you tried and it may have failed you? That way it will at least shown some effort on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can summarize the data as:

```
select world, count(*) as players, sum(online) as online, avg(level) as avglevel
from players
group by world;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update worlds w join
       (select world, count(*) as players, sum(online) as online, avg(level) as avglevel
        from players
        group by world
       ) p
       on w.world = p.world
    set w.players = p.player,
        w.online = p.online,
        w.avglevel = p.avglevel;
```

I don't think maintaining a separate table like this is a good idea.  After all, you can always just query `players` to get this information.  Also the two systems can quickly get out-of-date, so the data is inconsistent.  You would fix that by using triggers, but that adds complexity to the system.  In general, a simple query is quite sufficient.

Comment: My man! You solved it! I am going to use a cron job for this anyways so it will never be out of date. Thank you so much! I freaking love you, dude! I just found a few typos in your query, but I fixed it. Should be `on w.name = p.world` and `set w.players = p.players`. Thank you so sooooooooo much!

Comment: @LeeCheung . . . Even with a cron job, the table will be out-of-date.  You are better off using a view.  If you need this in a table for some reason, then you may need to explore triggers.